# Ajustar moeda usando o PHP

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte valor:

R$ 1.524,33

Preciso gravar no banco de dados, no formato: 1524.33

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a função `str_replace`:

```
<?
    $valor_sem_ponto = str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', "1.524,33"));
    echo $valor_sem_ponto;
?>
```

**Resultado**

> 1524.33